# 自作プログラムのライセンスの変更

Tags: ライセンス

これまで、GPL3で配布していた自作のプログラムのライセンスをMITなどに変更にして条件を緩和したいと思っています。

こういうことって著作権者でも許されるのでしょうか？

Answer (score 7):

自身の著作物であれば、次バージョンからライセンスを変更するのは問題ないと思います。
(すでにリリース済みのバージョンのプログラムのライセンスを変更するのは、いろいろと問題になると思いますが)

＃自身がライセンサであり一次配布元であるので、GPLの条項適用前という解釈です。
＃もちろん、自身のプログラムがGPLなソースコードを流用、リンクしていれば、MITライセンスへの変更は許可されないでしょう。

Comment: ありがとうございます。更にコードを書き換えた上に、名前を変えて別のアプリケーションとしてリリースすることにしました。